# « La vie qu'on a rêvé » : retour sur le pronom relatif, la préposition rattachée à l'antécédent et le sens du verbe correspondant ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, pronoms-relatifs, antécédent

Dans une chanson de Johnny Hallyday ([*Je ne suis qu'un homme*](https://youtu.be/cepAVgPXZ9c?t=123) ds. *Mon pays c'est l'amour*, 2018, Warner Music France) on trouve les paroles suivantes :

> [...]
> Prisonnier de l'instinct, on recherche encore
>   Un remède au destin, aux peines sur nos épaules
>   La vie qu'on a rêvé, noyée au fond des fioles
>   Au fond du cœur des Hommes
>
> [ Source : [genius.com](https://genius.com/Johnny-hallyday-je-ne-suis-quun-homme-lyrics) ]

[*Rêver*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%AAver) en emploi transitif au sens propre (voir en rêve) « se construit d'ordinaire avec *de*, parfois sans préposition, rarement avec *à*. » (« Les classiques donnaient souvent à *rêver* le sens de « méditer, penser » et le construisaient avec *sur* ou *à*, ou sans préposition [...] ») ; au sens figuré (imaginer etc.), « [...] il se construit avec *à* ou *de* ou sans préposition. ». On peut aussi trouver *rêver sur* avec un complément « qui n'exprime pas nécessairement l'objet du rêve, mais éventuellement un point de départ. » (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 290 f ; note H2 ; plus succinctement voir la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=r%C3%AAver&id=2187)).

Je me suis demandé pourquoi on avait le pronom [*que*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que) et non [*dont*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dont) ici, voire *à [laquelle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/laquelle)* ; l'emploi du pronom *dont* impose certaines [contraintes](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2904) « lorsque l'antécédent, c'est-à-dire le nom que remplace dont et qui le précède immédiatement, est lui-même déjà lié à la préposition *de* » et plus généralement il faudrait « veiller à respecter la correction syntaxique de toute la phrase » (BDL).

---

- À partir de la formulation dans la chanson, peut-on retracer à quelle
  préposition on réfère, et le sens précis de *rêver* en contexte ?
- Pouvait-on employer le pronom *dont* adéquatement ici et s'agirait-il
  du même sens que précédemment ; est-on du même avis pour *à/sur laquelle*  ?

Comment: L'erreur « rêvé » au lieu de « rêvée » vient-elle des paroles ?

Comment: Peut-être que la relation syntaxique serait plus proche à "on a rêvé (pendant toute) une vie"? Possibly an even bigger stretch. But then you'd have your "que", I think, and lack of agreement justified.

Comment: Bon, bon, j'ai utilisé une nouvelle source... voir au besoin ce [tableau-synthèse](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4221) pour alimenter la réflexion. Si quelqu'un achète encore des albums sur CD et que les paroles y sont incluses, on pourrait vérifier. J'ai regardé 10+ sites différents de paroles et il n'y a aucun consensus...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, on peut retrouver la proposition à laquelle on se réfère.

> On a rêvé **une** vie → La vie **qu'on** a rêvée
>
> On a rêvé **d'une** vie → La vie **dont** on a rêvé

Comme indiqué en source, *rêver à* n'est pas très utilisé mais ça donnerait :

> On a rêvé **à une** vie → La vie **à laquelle** on a rêvé

Le sens est sensiblement le même en utilisant *dont*, à mon avis ce choix a été motivé uniquement par une question de [pieds](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pied) (sens 4. c.)

Comment: Avec le méchant accord du participe passé, ça devrait être *la vie qu'on a rêvée* (faute déjà présente dans l'énoncé de la question).

Comment: @Greg La question contient *L**e** vie qu'on a révé*. Il n'y a donc pas de faute d'accord ;-) Je n'irais pas plus loins dans l'interprétation possible de cette retranscription très imparfaite des paroles de la chanson...

Answer (score -1):

Ne s'explique pas l'erreur « rêvé » pour « rêvée » (L'erreur est apparemment dans les [paroles](https://www.lacoccinelle.net/1318264-johnny-hallyday-je-ne-suis-qu-un-homme.html);). La suggestion dans un commentaire qu'il pourrait s'agir de la conjonction « que » (la vie pendant laquelle on a rêvé) est totalement inacceptable; « que » doit alors être interprété comme signifiant « pendant laquelle » et cela est de la pure invention. On trouve bien un cas d'utilisation de cette conjonction en connexion avec un substantif au lieu de ce qui est habituellement un verbe(TLFi) ou plus rarement un adverbe ;

> a) [Apposée à un subst.] Le sentiment que..., l'espoir que..., la crainte que... Le bruit court qu'il a eu un accident.
>    À l'idée que... V. idée I A 1 d. D'une heure à l'autre, à l'idée que j'écris, que je dois poursuivre, je m'écœure. Jamais je n'ai de sécurité, de certitude (G. BATAILLE, Exp. int., 1943, p. 181).

« Que », dans ces constructions, établit une détermination du concept présenté par ce qui la suit comme étant considéré sous l'aspect du type énoncé par le substantif : « j'écris » peut être considéré comme étant une idée, une certitude, un fait, un savoir, une suspicion, une révélation, et bien d'autres choses mais pas une vie.  « On a rêvé », de même, peut être toutes ces choses mais pas une vie ; notons que cette construction est sujette à ambigüité hors de contexte, « que » pouvant être pris pour le pronom relatif (l'attestation que j'écris).

Il est certain qu'il faut comprendre « rêver » dans un de ses sens transitifs relatif à l'état de veille et non du sommeil ; « que », comme pronom relatif objet force la transitivité et le contexte de la chanson l'état de veille. Il semble fortement que des trois sens dans cette catégorie dans le [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?11;s=2707329135;r=1;nat=;sol=0;) le premier soit celui qui convienne. Cependant je pense qu'il  ne s'agit pas  du syntagme « rêver sa vie ».

> (TLFi) B 1. Laisser emporter son imagination dans un univers mythique, poétique, dégagé des contingences du réel.
>   Qqn rêve qqc
>   - Je rêve pour vous un joli petit hôtel entre cour et jardin (...) un palais de fée dont vous seriez la reine et où je passerais ma vie à vos genoux.
>   - Je rêvais croisades, voyages de découvertes dont on n'a pas de relations, républiques sans histoires (...): je croyais à tous les enchantements.
>   *Rêver sa vie* 
>   - Admets que tu partes dans l'état où tu es en ce moment: tu risques de crever comme une bulle, tu auras rêvé ta vie trente-cinq ans et puis un beau jour une grenade fera éclater tes rêves, tu mourras sans t'être réveillé. Tu as été un fonctionnaire abstrait, tu seras un héros dérisoire.
>
> 2. Échafauder un projet qui semble réalisable.
> 3. Désirer ardemment, aspirer à.

Pourquoi écarter le sens « 2 » ? Il me semble qu'il ne s'agisse  pas du rêve « réfléchi », assez raisonnable, d'un projet ; « noyé au fond des fioles » évoque les brumes de l'alcool et non un soucis du réalisable. Il est plus difficile d'éliminer le sens « 3 » ; la seule argumentation en support du rejet de cette possibilité est la supposition que le désir ardent et l'aspiration ne sont pas des produits de l'enivrement en cela qu'étant, encore supposément, des états d'esprit durables, ils sont nécessairement une grande partie du temps sous l'examen du sujet pleinement conscient.

Selon le choix auquel on arrive ci-dessus sur la base des définitions du TLFi, il n'y a aucune possibilité, toujours selon cette base, de considérer une forme dans laquelle « à » ou « de » figurerait.

Comment: *Il est certain qu'il faille* ?? *Il me semble qu'il ne s'agisse...* ?? Pourquoi ces subjonctifs là où l'indicatif s'impose ?