# Where's the subject in "Le jour qui se rêve."

Tags: verbes-pronominaux, sujet, voix-passive

I'm listening to a song called "Le jour qui se rêve". It feels difficult to translate the title in my head.

I know 'se rêver' means to dream and, I may be wrong I couldn't find a lot of sentences using it, is followed by the preposition à.

And I know that 'qui' is a relative pronoun that replaces an indirect object after a preposition or the subject of the subordinate clause. So since se rêver is usually followed by à, then Le jour must be the indirect object qui describes or replaces.

But where's the subject of se rêver ,though?

There's even this sentence in the song that has the same problem too: Il était le jour qui se rêve.

The translation of the title is supposingly "The day that everyone dreams of"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there are two concepts that you need to understand: the usage of **qui** and the meaning of the reflexive.

The relative pronoun **qui** replaces a subject that has already been mentioned when that subject is also the subject of a subordinate clause. You can think of it like the word *that* in English, but note that *that* can be used for both subjects and objects of subordinate clauses, while French makes a distinction with **qui** and **que**:

- *The dog that sees me runs fast.* **Le chien qui me voit court vite.** (The dog is the subject of the subordinate clause, so we use **qui**.)
- *The dog that I see runs fast.* **Le chien que je vois court vite.** (The dog is the object of the subordinate clause, so we use **que**.)

So, in the phrase **Le jour qui se rêve**, you are right that it is **le jour** that is the subject of the whole phrase, and because **qui** is used, **le jour** is the subject of the verb **se rêver** in the subordinate clause as well. Note that this is not a complete sentence.

So what does **se rêver** mean? French uses reflexives in a wider variety of situations than English. In particular, French sometimes forms passive-like constructions with reflexives. In this case I would translate **le jour qui se rêve** as something like *the day that is dreamed of* or more liberally *the day that we dream of*.

Answer (score 3):

"Se rêver" is not a French pronominal verb, it has been invented for the purpose of the song.  A translation of the title can only be made after you know the song well and then it can be anything, one thing for some people and quite another for others; the interpretation of song and poetry is rarely unique.

This title is meant to rhyme with "Le jour qui se lève". "Se lever", when talking of the light of day, means "to begin to appear above the horizon at the end of the night time period".

This usage is strictly idiosyncratic, poetic or at least meant to be so: you don't say "le jour se rêve" in everyday French, in other words it means nothing; even if taken in the context of the song there is not necessarily a great analogy between what this title is supposed to rhyme with and what is being said; often, in numbers of such modern rhyming uses of the language there is nothing more than a gimmick. There is no deep meaning  imparted to the audience.

---

*Addition relative to a comment by **[user Manar](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43841/wheres-the-subject-in-le-jour-qui-se-r%c3%aave/43842?noredirect=1#comment89014_43842)***

*So what does se rêver mean? French uses reflexives in a wider variety of situations than English. In particular, French sometimes forms passive-like constructions with reflexives. In this case I would translate "le jour qui se rêve" as something like "the day that is dreamed of" or more liberally "the day that we dream of".* (**[user Dave](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43843/17649)**)

The remark about passive-like constructions is correct.

- Le son f de « paragraphe »  **s'écrit** avec « ph » et non f. (*est écrit*)
- Le français se parle dans certain pays Africains. (*est parlé*)
- Ces plats se mangent chauds ou froids. (*sont mangés*)
- Ces luxueuses villas se sont vendues facilement.(*ex. BDL - ont été vendues*)
- La guerre s'est déclarée en fin d'année. ex. (*ex. BDL - a été déclarée*)
- Ses problèmes se sont réglés alors qu'il n'y croyait plus. ex. (*ex. BDL - ont été réglés*)

In all these cases there is a precise correspondence to a passive form:
le son est écrit — le français est parlé — ces plats sont mangés — Ces villas sont vendues — La guerre est déclarée — Ses problèmes sont réglés

We must then have the same correspondance pour "le jour qui se rêve", and that is "Le jour est rêvé". However, this is not said; you can say "le jour dont on rêve". The closest you can come to that is in the idiom "**jour révé**", where "révé" is an *adjective* ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9v%C3%A9)).

There is no doubt you can say things such as the following, where the verb is seen to be a transitive verb, which would tend to make one think that the passive is immediate; this is not so.

- J'ai rêvé le jour où les vacances commenceraient.
- J'ai rêvé l'évènement avant qu'il devienne réalité.

I don't believe the passives for those sentences are correct. I have no reference for those particular ones but in what concerns the following there is one (Jean-Pierre Desclés et Zlatka Guentchéva, Le passif dans le système des voix du français)

- Jean sent la rose. (*These authors assert that "La rose est sentie par Jean." is not a correct sentence of French.*)

Therefore, if user Dave's conjecture is on first considerations full of good sense, on the ground of what we might call technicalities, for want of a perfect term, it is not a possibility. However, I could still be wrong for the case of "rêver", even though I have a strong impression that there is no natural passage to the passive form.

---

*Addition of the lyrics of the song "Le jour qui se rêve"*

Être seul, être cent
Et en vain tant la foule
Être cent, puis deux mille
Et quelqu'un qui écoute
Il était un jour qui se rêve
Il était un jour qui se rêve
Un sourire, un échange, rien de plus ordinaire
S'engager, toi et moi, ça doit pouvoir se faire
Il est là le jour qui se rêve
Le voilà le jour qui se rêve
Être seul, être cent au milieu de la foule
Être mille ou cent mille et le monde à l'écoute
Il était un jour qui se rêve
Il était un jour qui se rêve
Des sourires, qui s'échangent et qu'ils soient ordinaires
S'engager, toi et moi, on va devoir le faire
Il est là le jour qui se rêve
Le voilà le jour qui se rêve
Aujourd'hui on dit qu'il est temps
Maintenant on fait ce qu'on dit
Aujourd'hui on va de l'avant
Maintenant on va de la vie
Aujourd'hui on sait qu'il est temps
Maintenant on est ce qu'on dit
Aujourd'hui le jour qu'on attend
Maintenant on sait que c'est lui
Nanananananana
Le jour qui se rêve
Le jour qui se rêve
Le jour qui se rêve
Jamais seul, jamais cent et toujours dans la foule
Être mille ou cent mille et tout le monde qui l'écoute
Il est là le jour qui se rêve
Le voilà le jour qui se rêve
Aujourd'hui on dit qu'il est temps
Maintenant on fait ce qu'on dit
Aujourd'hui on va de l'avant
Maintenant on va de la vie
On sait qu'il est temps
On est ce qu'on dit
Le jour qu'on attend
C'est le jour qui se rêve
Nananananana
Le jour qui se rêve
Le jour qui se rêve
Le jour qui se rêve
Le jour qui se rêve
Le jour qui se rêve

Comment: Oh I can't believe I spent hours trying to guess the grammar behind this when it's just a gimmick  Idk about 'se rêver' not being a pronominal, I can't find it in any of the dictionaries online but it's still there on wikitionare (usage n.10 of rêver) https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%AAver

Comment: @Manar There is no definition of this form in the Wiktionary. They say "forme pronominale de 'rêver'", but then if it means simply "rêver" (which is nonsense since when there is a normal verb for a concept a pronominal form is never added so as to say the same thing) "le jour qui rêve" means nothing in normal today's French. The usage n° 10 means "imaginer être" and you need a complement; there is no complement in the song and anyway "le jour qui se rêve quelque chose" means nothing.

Comment: Could you check Dave's answer. Maybe it's correct and this is a passive form

Comment: I'm not advanced in french but I searched google books and I couldn't find "se rever" so I guess you're right. The reason I was so convinced it existed in first place was this post but I guess it was wrong afterall https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/484855

Comment: @Manar Yes, I just did so and the bit about a passive form might have something;  so I'll look at it and give you whatever explanation I can put together as an addition in my answer.

Comment: @Manar Right, that confirms what I was saying: a complement is necessary. Nevertheless, I'll look at this possibility of a passive form (I have nothing evident to tell you right away and I must think about it).

Comment: I can imagine saying something like "Je me rêve possédant une Porsche", following the same principle as "Je m'imagine xxx". But I agree "Le jour qui se rêve" doesn't make a lot of sense outside of a poetic context, I think your answer is fully right on that.

Comment: @Manar la forme est (ou était) utilisée en pratique. Je ne l'ai jamais vu a l'écrit. Mais à l'oral, dire "il se rêve une fille" est une forme populaire utilisée par les jeunes de mon époque pour dire "il aime cette fille (en secret)", cette fille est dans ses rêves. Expression probablement ringarde aujourd'hui chez les jeunes. Autre forme utilisée à la même époque par les même personnes "il se rêve" (sous entendu lui-même), qui se traduirait par "il se la pète", "il se prend pas pour une merde" ou en langage soutenu "il a un ego surdimensionné", ou dans certains cas "il se sur-estime".

Comment: Mais assez d'accord avec le fait que dans ce cas précis je ne pense pas qu'il y ait un sens commun. Moi j'entends un jeu de mot mal adroit, d'autant plus qu'on dit "Le jour se lève !" et pas "Le jour qui se lève ...". Deuxième forme qui laisse plutôt entendre que la phrase n'est pas finie. Ou encore que ce n'est pas le début de la phrase. Mais tel quel ça sonne faux.

Answer (score 2):

Dave's answer is right. He is just missing to state that *le jour qui se rêve* is also a pun (and not a gimmick).

***Rêver*** contrasts with ***vivre*** here.

We can oppose *un jour qui se vit* (a day to be lived/a day being lived in the real life) and *un jour qui se rêve* (a day "being dreamt of, a day to be lived in our imagination, a fantasy).

*Un jour **qui se** rêve* is different from *un jour **dont on** rêve* that primarily means "a day we dream of", i.e. a day we would love to live.

Here are a few examples of *se rêver* used that way (emphasis mine):

> Toi qui lui dis tout haut ce qu’il se dit tout bas,
> Le souffle qui le pousse et l’ombre qui le leurre,
> **Et tout ce qui se rêve** et tout ce qui se pleure,
> Et tout ce qui se chante et ne se parle pas.

Edouard Pailleron, L'immortelle, 1866

> Dans le moment même de l'action et de la parole, je suis ailleurs, je pense à autre chose; **ce qui se rêve** est tout pour moi.

Alfred de Vigny, Journal d'un poète, 1844

More recent ones:

> « Les romans de la Table Ronde. Des chevaliers de rêve, **des chevaliers qui se rêvent** ? »

Catherine Sevestre-Loquet

> C'est quoi l'amour ? Ce sont **deux vies qui se rêvent**, s'envolent, s'installent et parfois cohabitent.

[Emprise directe](https://www.lylo.fr/concert/b0e536-du-bout-des-levres-theatre-de-l-allegria-maison-des-arts-du-plessis-robinson)

> Les peaux se frôlent, se râpent, se heurtent et se mélangent. Un corps à corps, charnel et marionnettique. **Deux êtres qui se rêvent l’un l’autre** et comblent leur silence.

[Mano Labo](https://manolabo.wordpress.com/les-spectacles/une-ombre-chacun/)

and a famous direct transitive usage of rêver:

> J'ai rêvé New York

Yves Simon.

See also: [« La vie qu'on a rêvé » : retour sur le pronom relatif, la préposition rattachée à l'antécédent et le sens du verbe correspondant ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33756/la-vie-quon-a-r%c3%aav%c3%a9-retour-sur-le-pronom-relatif-la-pr%c3%a9position-rattach%c3%a9e)

Comment: I wanted to ask LBH today about the fact that "rêver" isn't always proceeded by a preposition, but I was hesitant because I didn't understand the difference between the one followed by de and without it. I'm so happy someone mentioned it!